# App Screen is blank when deployed through AppCenter

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Xamarin.Forms app built for iOS and Android.  The application works fine when tested from Visual Studio (in Debug or Release modes and on the emulator or a device). However, when I try to deploy it through AppCenter, the app works on iOS and on Android, it displays the SplashScreen and then a blank white page.  None of my controls show up at all...on iOS it is working fine, so the Views seem to be correct..

I hooked up the Android Device Monitor, but I do not seem to get any error messages.  I have tried several changes of the project properties (turning ProGuard and MultiDex on and off; changing the Linker settings), but nothing seems to change the behavior.

I am out of ideas to even look for the problem...does anyone have any suggestions?  Has anyone seen this before?  Is there anywhere that lists the differences in build between Visual Studio and AppCenter?

**UPDATE:** I have gotten some additional logging from the Device Monitor.  There are additional log entries in the version that works, so it seems that something is not running in the deployed version (maybe associated with Google Maps?).

The version not working has these two lines:

```
01-09 07:23:04.378: I/Google Maps Android API(11219): Google Play services client version: 11400000
01-09 07:23:04.709: I/LaunchCheckinHandler(1410): Displayed {my application name}/md582f1e314fc580d8ae4e7bb0d59c62d55.MainActivity,wp,ca,537
```

The version that works has these extra log entries:

```
01-09 07:28:29.970: I/Google Maps Android API(12443): Google Play services client version: 11400000
01-09 07:28:31.807: I/SFPerfTracer(735):      triggers: (rate: 0:0) (9563 sw vsyncs) (0 skipped) (121:40138 vsyncs) (123:54057)
01-09 07:28:32.279: I/SFPerfTracer(735):      triggers: (rate: 6:1097) (compose: 0:0) (post: 0:3) (render: 0:4) (125:27407 frames) (126:32007)
01-09 07:28:32.279: D/SFPerfTracer(735):        layers: (2:8) (StatusBar#0 (0xaf154000): 4:4927)* (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper#0 (0xaf113000): 0:228)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0#0 (0xaf10c000): 0:373)* (animation background stackId=1#0 (0xaf192000): 0:20)* (NavigationBar#0 (0xaf445000): 0:493) (com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#0 (0xaf424000): 0:14)* (com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher#1 (0xaf2fa000): 0:154)* ({my application name}/md582f1e314fc580d8ae4e7bb0d59c62d55.SplashActivity#0 (0xaf437000): 0:3)
01-09 07:28:32.514: W/zygote(12443): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md58432a647068b097f9637064b8985a5e0.ViewRenderer_2
01-09 07:28:32.652: W/zygote(12443): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ActivityIndicatorRenderer
01-09 07:28:32.764: I/ThermalEngine(967): Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg from  override
01-09 07:28:32.764: I/Thermal-Lib(721): Thermal-Lib-Client: Client request sent
01-09 07:28:32.947: W/zygote(12443): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.TableViewRenderer
01-09 07:28:33.055: W/zygote(12443): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.BaseCellView
01-09 07:28:33.055: W/zygote(12443): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.TextCellRenderer_TextCellView
01-09 07:28:33.083: W/zygote(12443): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.CellRenderer_RendererHolder
01-09 07:28:33.172: W/View(12443): requestLayout() improperly called by md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.ScrollViewContainer{3f9ae0f V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,1444} during layout: running second layout pass**
01-09 07:28:33.325: I/LaunchCheckinHandler(1410): Displayed {my application name}/md582f1e314fc580d8ae4e7bb0d59c62d55.MainActivity,wp,ca,3558
```

Can anyone translate these log messages into English so I have some idea where to look for the issue?  IS there something extra that needs to be done with Google Maps when it is deployed versus debug/testing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you building and signing the *.apk and then sending it to AppCenter or are you letting AppCenter build, and sign the *.apk for you through the Build option.

Comment: I am using the Build functions in AppCenter.  It builds, signs and distributes the app, which will install but after the Splash Screen it just displays a blank white screen.  Thanks

Comment: First thing I would do is check your AppCenter build settings and make sure the selected SDK for your Android build is at least the same version (or higher) of the SDK you're compiling against as defined in our Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Checked that.  All the options are set for Android 9.0 in both places.  Other suggestions? (Thanks for the help, BTW)

Comment: Hey Jerry, I'm running into a similar problem. Were you able to find a fix?

Comment: @Chucky - I am happy to say I did get it working again, but sadly, I didn't record what I did to get it working. I messed with a lot of different things and finally got it working about 3 days after this thread was going on. Looking back through my source control, I messed with the Linker & Proguard settings, and the Android Support Nuget versions - but I can't tell you which might have been the cause.

Comment: Exactly the same issue for me, I have added AppCenter SDK to register crashes or errors, and nothing seems to be bad. The other day I aligned the Xamarin.Android SDK versions ( local and AppCenter) and finally worked, but this morning happens again, without changes in the code, so it's weird. maybe it is something related to the Splashscreen, we are generating it with a specific activity.

Answer (score 0):

It may not relate to the OP's issue but I had the same symptom today:
App working fine on Android when deployed from VS.
Blank screen when deployed from the MDM provider (in my case this was Airwatch Workspace ONE).
No useful information provided in the logs and no errors occurred.

I fixed it by unchecking Android Options -> Use shared runtime